# If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import

Tags: python, url, django-urls

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'questions.urls' from '/home/aliasqar/Django/Online-quiz/Quiz/questions/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

```
`
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('quiz/', include("questions.urls")),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
`
```